# Different formatting styles for different columns in paracol environment

Tags: parcolumns

Is it possible to use, say different line spacing in different columns in paracol package?

**Hint**: Package paracol is intended to provide

> multi-column typesetting mechanism by which you produce multi-column
> (e.g., bilingual) document switching and sychronizing each
> corresponding part in “parallel”.

https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol

The manual does not address the question, at least not at a quick glance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/paracol) refers to the following macro (p. 14)

```
\definecolumnpreamble{col}{pream}
```

It is global setting and works as a switch meaning if you put it in the middle of document it affects all `paracol` environments from that point onward. You need to re-define the *pream* in order to remove the effect.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\begin{document}
\RaggedRight
\begin{paracol}{3}[\section*{No formatting}]
    \kant[1][1-2]
    \switchcolumn \kant[2][1]
    \switchcolumn \kant[3][1]
\end{paracol}

\bigskip

\definecolumnpreamble{1}{\bfseries\itshape}
\definecolumnpreamble{2}{\normalfont}
\begin{paracol}{5}[\section*{Formatting on}]
    \kant[1][1]
    \switchcolumn \kant*[2][1]
    \switchcolumn \kant*[3][1]
    \switchcolumn \kant*[4][1]
    \switchcolumn \kant*[5][1]
\end{paracol}

\bigskip

\begin{paracol}{3}
    \kant[1][1-2]
    \switchcolumn \kant[2][1]
    \switchcolumn \kant[3][1]
\end{paracol}

\bigskip

\definecolumnpreamble{1}{\relax}
\definecolumnpreamble{2}{\relax}
\begin{paracol}{5}[\section*{Formatting off}]
    \kant[1][1]
    \switchcolumn \kant*[2][1]
    \switchcolumn \kant*[3][1]
    \switchcolumn \kant*[4][1]
    \switchcolumn \kant*[5][1]
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set up material that's executed at the start of a column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\definecolumnpreamble{1}{\linespread{1.3}\selectfont\sloppy}
\begin{paracol}{2}

\kant[1-3]

\switchcolumn

\kant[4-6]

\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

The columns are numbered from 0.

[image]